# node "can't set headers after they are sent reset" how to render the same ejs page with different data with express

Tags: node.js, express

Here's my problem: I use nodejs with express to render an ejs page. I have a UI with a "see" button and my javascript opens the page with window.open.

With `app.get()` I render my page with `<% ... %>` parameters plus some javascript depending on what the user filled out in the UI. Which means that I have only one ejs able to collect various data.

What I do works perfectly locally but server-side it works the first time then I get the error on my second click:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at done (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:363:10)
    at View.render (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/ec2-user/firstnodeapp/expressUI.js:64:15
```

Basically what I want to do is to be able to clear everything I sent when I opened the first page to enable to set headers again. At least that's what I think.

If someone wants to help I can provide more information.

**Edit** : here's my expressUI.js (equivalent of server.js), it's a little messy but hope it helps.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
http = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(http);

const EventEmitter = require('events');
const util = require('util');

function MyEmitter() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(MyEmitter, EventEmitter);

require('./public/Tools/support.js')();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(readAll);

socketConnectionOn(io);

myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('download_ready', function(subscription_number) {
    console.log('express1')
    io.emit('download', subscription_number)
});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
      var chargify = require('chargify'),
          chargify_site = chargify('*name*', '*key*');
  chargify_site.get('subscriptions.json', function(err, res, body) {
    socket.emit('All Subscriptions', body);
  });

  });

    res.render('UI_design.ejs', {});

});


app.get('/subscription/:subscriptionID', function(req, res) {
  if (req.url != '/favicon.ico' && req.url != '/') {

    myEmitter.on('allRead', function(trnsctns, sbs, charges, payments, curr_charges, paym, stNumber, address, lastDate) {
  if (charges.length == 0) {
    res.render('PaymentArrayEmpty.ejs', {});
  } else {
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.emit('trs_data', charges, payments);
    });
    var async = require("async");
    async.parallel({list:function(callback) {
      var list = createListOfParameters(trnsctns, sbs.subscription, charges, payments, curr_charges, paym, address[0], address[3], address[4], stNumber, lastDate)
      callback(null, list);
    },
  },
  function(err, results) {
    console.log('Right subscription ID!');
      console.log(__dirname)
    res.render('nessa_invoice_5.ejs', results.list); 
  });

  }

  });
  }

});



app.get('/download/:subscriptionNb', function(req, res){
    console.log('expressDownload')
  var subscriptionID = req.url.substr(10)
  var file = __dirname + '/public/Tools/Invoices/statement_' + subscriptionID + '_' + todayString() + '.pdf';
  res.download(file)
});


http.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

What I want to do is that "res.render('nessa_invoice_5.ejs', results.list);" works several times.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add routes definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick!
Actually I didn't understand because in my last versions of the code I could render the page several times and then I couldn't. I don't really understand why it works, but here's a solution in case someone has a similar problem.

You just have to put the

```
myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('download_ready', function(subscription_number) {
    console.log('express1')
    io.emit('download', subscription_number)
});
```

inside the

```
app.get('/subscription/:subscriptionID', function(req, res) {
  if (req.url != '/favicon.ico' && req.url != '/') {
//code
}
});
```

, at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Means

You are trying to send the response more than once from your server for a particular request.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I read that and actually that's what happens in my code. But I want to do that.
I want to render the same ejs file several times, only changing the data in it but keeping the same html structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `res.render()` you must be using `ejs.renderFile()` or ejs.compile() and manually send the response once after every thing is rendered, manipulated and arranged  as per your needs. The following link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923033/3359432

Comment: I like your idea. I tested it but I don't know how it really helps: basically it enables me to delay the res.send.
But actually I need to send the result otherwise my web page is blank. Every time i want to see a page I need to send the results and after clear everything to be able to send another page based on the same ejs.

Comment: @Tchak Thats how it works. You cannot send multiple HTML pages on a single request. Actually what I meant is render all the pages independently and combine them into a single response and then res.send them as a single response/HTML file so that you will not need to send headers multiple times..